# Is it true that I can't use the Telerik Asp.NET MVC Controls from Codeplex in commercial applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, nuget

Is it true that I can't use the Telerik ASP.NET MVC Controls from Codeplex or NuGet in commercial applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use the CodePlex source if it is an application for internal use or GPLv2 open source app.

Read the [License FAQ](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx) for a summarized version.

> **Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Open Source GPL (Open Source License)**
>   This is a suitable option if you are building an application for internal use or an open source application with a license compatible with the GNU GPL v2.0.
>
> **Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Commercial License (Developer License with Subscription and Priority Support)**
>   This is a suitable option if you are building closed-source commercial products for redistribution or if you wish to avoid integrating open-source components into your application.
>   This license is provided per developer, so you need to purchase the appropriate number of developer seats from Telerik.

Comment: It appears that the license defines "redistribution" as sending the executable/dll to a 3rd party.  Under that definition, hosting a website using Telerik controls does not qualify as redistribution.  Therefore, even a commercial website application can use the open source license.  Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @ARM, IANAL, but as long as the commercial website is compatible with the GNU GPLv2.0 license, then I believei t would be allowed.